# Determine the arithmetic and geometric sequence given the relationships betweeen the first four terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

No matter what I try, I can't solve this problem. I'm almost done but I need to get just one more thing to be able to finish it.

> **Problem**
>
> The first, second and fourth term of the arithmetic and of the geometric sequence are equal, respectively. The third term of the arithmetic sequence is by $18$ greater than the third term of the geometric sequence. Determine both sequences.

---

*My attempt*

I first wrote down the relationships between the terms.
$$a_1=b_1$$
$$a_2=b_2$$
$$a_3=b_3+18$$
$$a_4=b_4$$
We can rewrite the last three relationships as
$$a_1+d=b_1r$$
$$a_1+2d=b_1r^2+18$$
$$a_1+3d=b_1r^3$$
Then we can square $a_2=b_2$
$$a^2_2=(a_1+d)^2=b^2_2=(b_1r)^2$$
Rewrite $(b_1r)^2$
$$(b_1r)^2=b^2_1r^2=b_1b_1r^2=b_1b_3$$
So, we now know that $a^2_2=b_1b_3$. Based on that, we can write
$$(a_1+d)^2=b_1b_3$$
And since $b_1=a_1$
$$(a_1+d)^2=a_1b_3$$
We also know that $a_3=b_3+18 \leftrightarrow b_3=a_3-18$
$$(a_1+d)^2=a_1(a_3-18)$$
Which gives
$$(a_1+d)^2=a_1(a_1+2d-18)$$
Now, let's rewrite that as
$$a^2_1+d^2+2a_1d=a^2_1+2a_1d-18a_1$$
From that we have
$$d^2+18a_1=0$$
*Now I just need to get another equation to form a system of equations. From that, I can get $d$ or $a_1$, and then I can use the variable that I've got to get the second variable (i.e. the one I did not got). When I get $a_1$, I also get $b_1$ since $a_1=b_1$. Then I'll have $d$, $a_1$ and $b_1$. If I know these variables, I can easily get $r$. And then I can finally write out both sequences.*

---

Of course, I also have the solution. It is

> Arithmetic sequence: $$\langle-2,4,10,16,...\rangle$$
>  Geometric sequence: $$\langle-2,4,-8,16,...\rangle$$

Comment: Why are you bothering to work with $b$. Just use: $a=a$, $ar=a+d$, $ar^2=a+2d-18$, $ar^3=a+3d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the AP be $u_n=a+(n-1)d$ and the GP be $v_n=ar^{n-1}$.

\begin{align}
  a+d &= ar  \tag{$u_2=v_2$} \\
  a &= \frac{d}{r-1} \tag{1} \\
  a+3d &= ar^3  \tag{$u_4=v_4$} \\
  a &= \frac{3d}{r^3-1} \tag{2} \\
  r^3-1 &= 3(r-1) \tag{$2) \div (1$} \\
  (r-1)(r^2+r+1) &= 3(r-1) \\
  (r-1)(r^2+r-2) &= 0 \\
  (r-1)^2(r+2) &= 0 \\
  r &= -2 \tag{reject $r=1$} \\
  d &= -3a \\
  a+2d &= ar^2+18 \tag{$u_3=v_3+18$} \\
  a-6a &= 4a+18 \\
  a &= -2 \\
  d &= 6
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Here we know that $r\neq1$ otherwise all terms would be equal and it would not be possible to have the third term of the AP being greater than the third term of the GP.

Let $T_i$ be the $i-$th term of the AP.

$$\begin{align}
\frac {T_4-T_2}{T_2-T_1}&=\frac {4-2}{2-1}\\
\frac {r^3-r}{r-1}&=2
&&\scriptsize (T_i=ar^{i-1}\text{ for } i=1,2,4)\\
r^2+r-2&=0
&&\scriptsize (\text{as }r\neq 1)\\
(r-1)(r+2)&=0\\
r&=-2 
&&\scriptsize (\text{as } r\neq 1)\\ \\ 
T_2-T_1=d&=a(r-1)\\
d&=-3a\\ \\
T_3=a+2d&=18+ar^2\\
a-6a&=18+4a\\
a&=-2\\\\
\Longrightarrow d&=6
\end{align}$$

Hence

- $\color{red}{\text{AP}: \qquad -2,4,10,16}$
- $\color{red}{\text{GP}:\qquad -2,4,-8, 16}$